# Geometry nodes: calculate the cross sectional area of a moving object

Tags: geometry-nodes, physics

I'm trying to model the drag force (Fd) on flying objects. I would like to make the model procedural, so in which I now choose to use points, on which I later can instance.

The drag force formula is:

[image]  , in which *A* is the cross sectional area of the object.

To calculate this area of any possible instance procedurally, it was my idea to use the following method:

[image]

- Use a `bounding box` to make the size of a `grid` fit the outer edges of the instance;
- Using a `raycast` node to make a projection of the cross sectional area with a `face area` node;
- Use the moving direction (vector: d(t)) of the objects for the ray direction. This is different for all points.

Example with an object info node:

[image]

However, the problem is that the `raycast` node does not work on a point cloud (obviously because it does not contain any geometry) and not on vertices (because they don't contain faces). In addition, I suspect that this method would calculate the total drag force of all instances and not that of an individual instance, which would, of course, calculate the wrong drag force for each instance.

How could I procedural determine the cross sectional area of individual, flying instances in the direction of the vector in which they move?

Comment: How are you stashing the direction of travel.. on the points before instancing on them? Are the instances at varying orientations with respect to those directions?

Comment: Direction of travel is calculated by the subtraction of two positions. Yes the instances could have varying orientations, so that some travel faster then others (because of the drag force).

Comment: Witch shape have your particles? If they are spherical the surface of circle will do, it's the base of a cone witch based on the previous location.

Comment: It is procedural, so it could be anything.